# How to insert string value into specific column value on python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data=['ABC1','ABC2','ABC3','ABC4']
data = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["Column A"])



    Column A
0   ABC1
1   ABC2
2   ABC3
3   ABC4
```

How to insert "-" a ABC on column A of data?

Output:

```
  Column A
0   ABC-1
1   ABC-2
2   ABC-3
3   ABC-4
```

Comment: Surely your actual problem can't be this straightforward... can you provide a more substantial [mcve] that more accurately represents your data? The solution to this is str.replace with backreferences, but may not be so for your actual data.

Comment: i.e., `replace(r'(ABC)', r'\1-') `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Simplest solution to Use `replace` method as a regex and `inplace` method to make it permanent in the dataframe.

```
>>> data['Column A'].replace(['ABC'], 'ABC-', regex=True, inplace=True)
print(data)
  Column A
0    ABC-1
1    ABC-2
2    ABC-3
3    ABC-4
```

Comment: I dont know why someone have downvoted the solution, any reason?

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is

```
data['Column A'] = data['Column A'].str[:-1] + '-' + data['Column A'].str[-1]
print (data)
#  Column A
#0    ABC-1
#1    ABC-2
#2    ABC-3
#3    ABC-4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way which only assumes that the numbers to be preceded by a dash are at the end:

```
df['ColumnA'].str.split('([A-z]+)(\d+)').str.join('-').str.strip('-')

0    ABC-1
1    ABC-2
2    ABC-3
3    ABC-4
```

Another example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA':['asf1','Ads2','A34']})
```

Will give:

```
df['ColumnA'].str.split('([A-z]+)(\d+)').str.join('-').str.strip('-')

0    asf-1
1    Ads-2
2     A-34
```